# Receiving the file with 0 byte at the side of client in android?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sockets

I am transferring the file by using socket programming in android
the file transferred successfully but when i open that file at client side it does not contain any data in that it contains 0 byte data

My client side code goes here:

```
 byte [] mybytearray  = new byte [filesize];
InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("/storage/sdcard0/Abstract.docx");
BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
bytesRead = is.read(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length);
current = bytesRead;


do {
   bytesRead =is.read(mybytearray, current, (mybytearray.length-current));
   if(bytesRead >=0)
   {
       current += bytesRead;
   }
} while(bytesRead > -1);

bos.write(mybytearray, 0 , current);
bos.flush();
long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

System.out.println(end-start);
bos.close();
socket.close();
```

and My server side code goes here

```
 while (true) {
 Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
 ////////////////////////////////
 File myfile=new File("/storage/sdcard0/Abstract.docx");
 byte[] mybytearray=new byte[(int)myfile.length()];
 FileInputStream fis =new FileInputStream(myfile);
 BufferedInputStream  bis=new BufferedInputStream(fis);
 bis.read(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length);
 OutputStream os=socket.getOutputStream();
 System.out.println("Sending.........");
 msg.setText("Sending 123.exe..........");
 os.write(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length);
 os.flush();
 socket.close();
 //////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 count++;
 message += "#" + count + " from " + socket.getInetAddress()
   + ":" + socket.getPort() + "\n";

 MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

  @Override
  public void run() {
   msg.setText(message);
  }
 });

 SocketServerReplyThread socketServerReplyThread = new SocketServerReplyThread(
   socket, count);
 socketServerReplyThread.run();

}
```

I am running it on my phones not on emulator

Comment: `the file transferred successfully` ??? What do you mean? 0 bytes is success?

Comment: `byte [] mybytearray  = new byte [filesize];`. filesize? Please elaborate.

Comment: My  filesize=6022386 its a variable value  and my file is of 11 kb but when i run the program then my file copied to the client succesfully with the extension  but it does not contain any data in that

Comment: `my file copied to the client succesfully with the extension but it does not contain any data in that`. How can you say that it 'copied successfully' where it is 0 bytes? That sentence makes no sense. You should say: `the file is not copied at all. Only a file of 0 bytes is created by my code.`.

Comment: What is the value of `current` when download is done for that 11 KB file? And how many bytes is that file exactly?

Comment: ooops ,Now error comes application unfortunately closed is there any code instead i am trying since so many days  can you please share it  if you have